# how to catch IndexNotFoundException with RestHighLevelClient 6.5.0

Tags: resthighlevelclient

I want to save data to es, but before save operation, i need always check 
 whether or not the index exists;
because the `restHighLevelClient`'s bulk method never throws any exception about IndexNotFoundException; therefore it will make performance lower.

Is there any way to catch the `IndexNofFoundException` with restHighLevelClient SDK?

Thanks for all kind of you

Answer (score 0):

Why not check if the index exist before putting the request in the bulk request?

final boolean exists = restHighLevelClient.indices().exists(new GetIndexRequest(indexName), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

Or you could check the message of the potential exceptions if they contain the literal text "index_not_found_exception"